# What's wrong with this c++ program? it core dump

Tags: c++

why it core dump? It first call derived's foo, in the method of foo, it call the base's foo, right?

```
struct base {
    virtual void foo() {};
};

struct derived : public base {
    void foo() { base:foo(); }
};

int main() {
    base* b = new derived();
    b->foo();

    delete b;
}
```

Comment: My compiler warned me: `'base': unreferenced label`. And this rang a bell.

Comment: This is why  you enable warnings, and fix them. Try `-Wall -Wextra` with *gcc* and *clang* for a very reasonable basic set of warnings, and add `-Werror` to force yourself to fix them. I seem to remember that `/W:4` was ok for MSVC, but google or try it out to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program crashes, because the stack overflows. And this is because you call `foo()` recursively forever

```
struct derived : public base {
    void foo() { base:foo(); }
};
```

The important part is `base:foo();`, see the missing colon? This is the same as a label and then calling `foo();`

```
base:
    foo();
```

---

Unrelated, when you build this with gcc and option `-Wall`, you will get two warnings

> ```
>    a.cpp: In member function 'virtual void derived::foo()':
>     a.cpp:6:18: warning: label 'base' defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
>          void foo() { base:foo(); }
>               ^
>     a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>     a.cpp:13:12: warning: deleting object of polymorphic class type 'base' which has non-virtual destructor might cause undefined behaviour         [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
>          delete b;
>                 ^
> ```

Comment: This is the answer which contains the actual reason for the crash: stack overflow.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a colon in `base:foo();`, oddly enough turning it into a label and a recursive call.

```
void foo()
{ 
   base:
     foo();
 }
```

Add a second : to make it a call to the base class function `base::foo();`

Answer (score 1):

You lose a ':'.

`base:foo();` should be `base::foo();`